# What is the violin song in My Hero Academia Season 4 Episode 20 played at 20:28?

Tags: my-hero-academia

What is the song in My Hero Academia Season 4 Episode 20 played at 20:28? It seems to be a solo violin piece that is beautiful and passionate. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The song is called "Dependable! Cheerful Person" Wind Adlib. It's on the OST for the first two seasons as best as I can tell. You can hear the full song on Soundcloud [here](https://soundcloud.com/xeno-sound2/06-yo-go-youki-mono-kaze-no-adlib).